# NFC send large file to another devices

Tags: nfc, android-file, nfc-p2p

How do I send files to and from devices using NFC beam. I tried the Google tutorials
to [send a file](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html) and [receive a file](http://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/receive-files.html)

I searched around the internet and didn't find any good tutorials.

Comment: I know how to send files the code here is                        File fileToTransfer = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), filePath);   fileToTransfer.setReadable(true, false);

    nfcAdapter.setBeamPushUris(
      new Uri[] { Uri.fromFile(fileToTransfer) }, this);

Comment: how to receive the NFC file in the project